# git pull generates "fatal: No remote repository specified." error

Tags: git, github

I want to start contributing to a project hosted on Github. I have taken the following steps:

1. git init
2. git pull https://github.com/PrincetonUniversity/EVCM.git

The pull command succeeded and the files where copied to my local directory. But when I try git pull again, then I get the following error

"fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
remote name from which new revisions should be fetched."

I did not get this error when I pulled from and pushed to other Github repositories in the past. What is the problem and how can I fix it? Could it be because I have pulled the same repository to a different local directory in the past? In either case, what should I do to fix the problem?

Comment: You want to start with a `git clone`, not init or pull.

Comment: It's ok not to start with a `git clone`. Just follow what the answers below suggest and do a `git remote add origin`. And please accept the answer that worked for you.

Comment: If you want to contribute to a project it would be best to fork it and work on your fork. You can read how to do it in the GitHub guide https://guides.github.com/activities/forking/

Answer (score 40):

You need to follow the correct steps.

You already did `git init`, then add remote by doing this.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/PrincetonUniversity/EVCM.git
```

Now the working tree can recognize `origin` so

```
git pull origin master
```

That's all and I hope it would be helpful to you.

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

You should always start with a `git clone` (and I'd suggest you do that), but if you want to continue from here, here's the way:

You can use `git remote add origin https://github.com/PrincetonUniversity/EVCM.git` to add a remote, and set its name to `origin`. You can check [this tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/) if you want to know more. This, I hope, will fix your problem. If you encounter other problems, just do a `git clone`.

Answer (score 15):

According to git's command line:

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> <local branch>
```

This would allow you to simply run **"git pull"** instead of **"git pull origin branch"**

Answer (score 4):

first do `git remote add origin 
https://github.com/PrincetonUniversity/EVCM.git`

then do `git pull origin`
here is a good tutorial https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-pull

but if you use git clone it will create automatically the `origin`for you.