# After I clone the remote repository how can I access on my IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

After I clone the remote repository how can I access on my IntelliJ IDEA? I just cloned it and now I want work on it
perhaps update code inside. I tried to pull it and I get this error:

> fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
>   remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.

Any idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34444169/git-pull-generates-fatal-no-remote-repository-specified-error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like no remote is configured for the repository.
In IDEA, you can configure remotes using the **VCS - Git - Remotes...** dialog. Add the remote repository there, and you should be able to fetch/pull